# Long boot time Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, upgrade, kernel

Hello I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on my T420 with 6GB RAM, Intel Pentium i5-2520M  and Intel HD3000. I have dual-boot alongside with Windows 10. I am wondering why (after upgrade from 16.04) Ubuntu 18.04  is booting so long. Here are some info:

---

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

---

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" 
character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @41.691s
└─multi-user.target @41.691s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @31.971s +20ms
    └─snapd.service @27.445s +4.524s
      └─basic.target @27.429s
        └─sockets.target @27.429s
          └─snapd.socket @27.375s +54ms
            └─sysinit.target @27.336s
              └─cryptsetup.target @27.336s
                └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @2.708s
                  └─-.mount @2.692s
                    └─system.slice @2.708s
                      └─-.slice @2.692s
```

---

```
systemd-analyze && system-analyze blame
```

---

```
     22.399s dev-sda6.device
     22.079s systemd-journal-flush.service
     19.299s keyboard-setup.service
     14.633s systemd-udevd.service
      9.882s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      4.776s apport-autoreport.service
      4.524s snapd.service
      4.373s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.905s NetworkManager.service
      3.677s udisks2.service
      3.509s plymouth-start.service
      2.738s thermald.service
      2.640s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      2.266s grub-common.service
      2.130s accounts-daemon.service
      1.833s apparmor.service
      1.784s dns-clean.service
      1.621s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
      1.599s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.541s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-54.mount
      1.540s snap-core-5742.mount
      1.510s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
      1.505s ModemManager.service
      1.463s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
      1.417s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
      1.406s colord.service
      1.358s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
      1.356s console-setup.service
      1.355s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.229s fwupd.service
      1.035s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
       958ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-354e4b40\x2dfa51\x2d43b8\x2d8584\x2d6acff1ee6ccd.swap
       955ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-43.mount
       808ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-117.mount
       755ms systemd-sysctl.service
       732ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       707ms avahi-daemon.service
       706ms networking.service
       697ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       696ms dev-hugepages.mount
       693ms systemd-modules-load.service
       689ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
       683ms dev-mqueue.mount
       654ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-40.mount
       638ms rsyslog.service
       622ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-808.mount
       604ms systemd-random-seed.service
       584ms snap-core-5548.mount
       553ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
       503ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
       491ms apport.service
       485ms bluetooth.service
       477ms systemd-logind.service
       475ms speech-dispatcher.service
       467ms gpu-manager.service
       466ms pppd-dns.service
       306ms user@120.service
       265ms systemd-journald.service
       259ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       256ms gdm.service
       222ms packagekit.service
       163ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       150ms systemd-resolved.service
       135ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-199.mount
       134ms polkit.service
       129ms upower.service
       126ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       123ms systemd-rfkill.service
       104ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
        99ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        75ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
        75ms bolt.service
        62ms user@1000.service
        57ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        55ms dev-loop19.device
        55ms dev-loop18.device
        54ms dev-loop17.device
        54ms snapd.socket
        54ms dev-loop16.device
        53ms dev-loop15.device
        53ms dev-loop14.device
        52ms dev-loop13.device
        52ms snap-core-5662.mount
        51ms dev-loop12.device
        51ms dev-loop11.device
        50ms dev-loop10.device
        50ms dev-loop9.device
        50ms dev-loop8.device
        49ms dev-loop7.device
        49ms dev-loop6.device
        49ms dev-loop5.device
        48ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
        48ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        48ms dev-loop4.device
        29ms ufw.service
        28ms setvtrgb.service
        20ms snapd.seeded.service
        17ms dev-loop3.device
        17ms dev-loop2.device
        16ms dev-loop1.device
        16ms dev-loop0.device
        12ms alsa-restore.service
        11ms dev-loop20.device
        11ms kerneloops.service
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms rtkit-daemon.service
         5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

---

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

---

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name 
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7b0ee565-f292-4853-8190-2c77fc5920a9 /               ext4    
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=354e4b40-fa51-43b8-8584-6acff1ee6ccd none            swap    sw              
0       0
```

---

```
dmesg
```

---

```
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2e, 
date = 2018-04-10
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-39-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-054) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-39.42-generic 4.15.18)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=7b0ee565-f292-4853-8190-2c77fc5920a9 ro quiet splash noresume vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] Disabled fast string operations
...
...
...
...
...
...
[    9.470172] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    9.470181] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    9.470288] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    9.470309] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   10.037672] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   10.047501] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   10.295572] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   10.523621] systemd-journald[272]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   27.020529] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   27.044240] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   27.055302] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   27.055320] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   27.055320] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   27.055324] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   27.055327] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   27.055333] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   27.064459] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   27.067017] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   27.073182] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.PMIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   27.073190] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   27.073193] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   27.073198] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   27.073200] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   27.073204] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   27.073206] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   27.073210] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   27.073211] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   27.075864] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[   27.075866] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[   27.076106] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   27.082691] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   27.087107] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[   27.087108] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   27.087109] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 83ET79WW (1.49 ), EC unknown
[   27.087110] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T420, model 4236EV9
[   27.089962] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   27.089984] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[   27.089985] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[   27.093935] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   27.095816] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[   27.100589] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input10
[   27.115016] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   27.163560] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 163840 ms ovfl timer
[   27.163561] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-16 Joules
[   27.163562] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-16 Joules
[   27.163562] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-16 Joules
[   27.173883] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   27.173884] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   27.210926] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   27.210928] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   27.210929] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   27.210933] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   27.271318] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20590: BIOS auto-probing.
[   27.271791] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20590: line_outs=1 (0x1f/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   27.271794] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   27.271796] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x1c/0x19/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   27.271798] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   27.271799] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   27.271802] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x23
[   27.271803] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1b
[   27.271805] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Dock Mic=0x1a
[   27.273167] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[   27.286383] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   27.286431] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   27.286477] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   27.286524] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   27.286565] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   27.286605] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[   27.286646] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[   27.317998] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   27.334325] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   27.350872] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b221)
[   27.353397] uvcvideo 1-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[   27.353400] uvcvideo 1-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   27.353402] uvcvideo 1-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   27.353482] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input18
[   27.353566] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   27.353567] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   27.400952] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   27.666956] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   27.684366] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   27.684368] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   27.684370] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   27.684371] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN, REV=0xB0
[   27.716892] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   27.718395] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.709212] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=664 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.709216] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=664 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.709219] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=664 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.710300] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=665 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.710904] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.710907] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.710910] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.710912] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.711247] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.324:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=666 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.712133] audit: type=1400 audit(1542478859.328:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=668 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   32.808397] Adding 11706364k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:11706364k FS
[   34.663689] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.663691] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.663694] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   39.075794] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   39.292343] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   39.353824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   39.360498] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   39.655291] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   39.739306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   39.808250] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   46.096432] wlp3s0: authenticate with 64:70:02:c0:71:8c
[   46.099360] wlp3s0: send auth to 64:70:02:c0:71:8c (try 1/3)
[   46.101581] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   46.105091] wlp3s0: associate with 64:70:02:c0:71:8c (try 1/3)
[   46.109167] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 64:70:02:c0:71:8c (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   46.115834] wlp3s0: associated
[   47.140483] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   59.271365] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

---

I tried to renamig the

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

to

```
RESUME=none
```

but it didn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.
Q.

**UPDATE 1**: I will mention that I have the swap partition

---

```
sudo blkid | grep swap
```

---

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="354e4b40-fa51-43b8-8584-6acff1ee6ccd" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2da700c0-05"
```

---

Should I edit the `resume` file as it was before, with the swap UUID? Q.

**UPDATE 2**: Should I mount the Windows partition to read only?
I found something interesting about `systemd-journald` [#20](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/493151-Boot-failing-on-quot-systemd-journald-XXX-Received-request-to-flush-runtime-journal-from-PID-1-quot?p=2611365#post2611365). I think the problem is with `systemd-journald`, am I right? On `dmesg` is line

> `[   10.523621] systemd-journald[272]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1`

Is this the culprid? Q.

**UPDATE 3**: Here is `systemd-analyze plot` result:

[image: img]

**UPDATE 3**: I've earned some seconds by removing `splash` parameter in `/etc/default/grub` file. Here are the results:

---

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

---

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @27.886s
└─gdm.service @27.360s +525ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @27.353s +3ms
    └─network.target @27.350s
      └─NetworkManager.service @23.588s +3.760s
        └─dbus.service @23.508s
          └─basic.target @23.471s
            └─sockets.target @23.470s
              └─snapd.socket @23.458s +10ms
                └─sysinit.target @23.386s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @23.245s +139ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @23.102s +116ms
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @2.980s +20.121s
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @2.626s +275ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @2.325s
                            └─system.slice @2.325s
                              └─-.slice @2.309s
```

---

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

---

```
 20.121s systemd-journal-flush.service
 18.777s dev-sda6.device
 17.743s keyboard-setup.service
 12.741s systemd-udevd.service
  4.868s apport-autoreport.service
  4.274s networkd-dispatcher.service
  3.760s NetworkManager.service
  3.488s udisks2.service
  3.025s thermald.service
  2.941s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  1.668s snapd.service
  1.547s accounts-daemon.service
  1.499s rsyslog.service
  1.212s colord.service
  1.114s ModemManager.service
  1.063s fwupd.service
  1.012s avahi-daemon.service
   996ms gpu-manager.service
   710ms bolt.service
   671ms dns-clean.service
   618ms motd-news.service
   550ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   535ms networking.service
   525ms gdm.service
   506ms snapd.seeded.service
   424ms user@120.service
   348ms systemd-sysctl.service
   314ms packagekit.service
   314ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   285ms grub-common.service
   284ms polkit.service
   281ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-354e4b40\x2dfa51\x2d43b8\x2d8584\x2d6acff1ee6ccd.swap
   275ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   269ms systemd-modules-load.service
   251ms dev-mqueue.mount
   249ms dev-hugepages.mount
   244ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   242ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   234ms systemd-logind.service
   229ms apparmor.service
   220ms systemd-resolved.service
   208ms wpa_supplicant.service
   205ms kerneloops.service
   198ms systemd-journald.service
   188ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   176ms plymouth-read-write.service
   174ms systemd-random-seed.service
   149ms apport.service
   139ms systemd-timesyncd.service
   137ms ufw.service
   135ms upower.service
   134ms speech-dispatcher.service
   116ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   112ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   108ms systemd-rfkill.service
   102ms setvtrgb.service
   100ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
    62ms user@1000.service
    34ms bluetooth.service
    24ms alsa-restore.service
    14ms pppd-dns.service
    10ms snapd.socket
     7ms ureadahead-stop.service
     6ms rtkit-daemon.service
     5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
     3ms console-setup.service
     3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
     2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

---

```
systemd-analyze time
```

---

```
Startup finished in 7.035s (kernel) + 28.638s (userspace) = 35.673s
graphical.target reached after 27.886s in userspace
```

---

## After removing `splash` parameter

I saw something interesting. After removing `splash` parameter, while OS was booting the backlight faded out little bit and `systemd-journal-flush.service` was written on the screen. Anyone can confirm is this something i should get rid of? Thanks. Q.

**UPDATE 4**: I'm trying to reduce the boot time by editing the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file. I've changed the settings to:

```
#Storage=volatile
#SystemMaxUse=16M
```

And the result after reboot is:

---

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

---

```
graphical.target @25.840s
└─gdm.service @25.656s +182ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @25.649s +3ms
    └─network.target @25.647s
      └─NetworkManager.service @22.262s +3.384s
        └─dbus.service @21.531s
          └─basic.target @21.478s
            └─sockets.target @21.477s
              └─snapd.socket @21.308s +163ms
                └─sysinit.target @21.288s
                  └─swap.target @21.288s
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-354e4b40\x2dfa51\x2d43b8\x2d8584\x2d6acff1ee6ccd.swap @21.050s +237ms
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-354e4b40\x2dfa51\x2d43b8\x2d8584\x2d6acff1ee6ccd.device @21.049s
```

---

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

---

```
 19.898s dev-sda6.device
 17.570s keyboard-setup.service
 16.376s systemd-journal-flush.service
 14.738s systemd-sysctl.service
 14.633s systemd-udevd.service
  4.082s networkd-dispatcher.service
  3.517s apport-autoreport.service
  3.384s NetworkManager.service
  3.321s udisks2.service
  2.389s snapd.service
  2.176s systemd-random-seed.service
  1.646s thermald.service
  1.455s accounts-daemon.service
  1.452s ModemManager.service
  1.364s grub-common.service
  1.175s colord.service
  1.056s wpa_supplicant.service
   969ms fwupd.service
   844ms systemd-modules-load.service
   815ms apport.service
   810ms avahi-daemon.service
   789ms bluetooth.service
   781ms gpu-manager.service
 19.898s dev-sda6.device
 17.570s keyboard-setup.service
 16.376s systemd-journal-flush.service
 14.738s systemd-sysctl.service
 14.633s systemd-udevd.service
  4.082s networkd-dispatcher.service
  3.517s apport-autoreport.service
  3.384s NetworkManager.service
  3.321s udisks2.service
  2.389s snapd.service
  2.176s systemd-random-seed.service
  1.646s thermald.service
  1.455s accounts-daemon.service
  1.452s ModemManager.service
  1.364s grub-common.service
  1.175s colord.service
  1.056s wpa_supplicant.service
   969ms fwupd.service
   844ms systemd-modules-load.service
   815ms apport.service
   810ms avahi-daemon.service
   789ms bluetooth.service
   781ms gpu-manager.service
```

---

```
systemd-analyze time
```

---

```
Startup finished in 4.940s (kernel) + 25.927s (userspace) = 30.868s
graphical.target reached after 25.840s in userspace
```

---

## `systemd-journal-flush.service` get rid of it?

I'm still trying to get rid of that `systemd-journal-flush.service`. Should I mask it? Any suggestions? Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem solved!

After few hours of thinking, I decided to mask the `systemd-journal-flush.service` and the `keyboard-setup.service`:

`systemctl mask systemd-journal-flush keyboard-setup`

So the final result is:

---

`systemd-analyze time`

---

```
Startup finished in 8.318s (kernel) + 21.910s (userspace) = 30.228s
graphical.target reached after 20.449s in userspace
```

---

**Profits:** ~60s - ~30s = ~30s

Do not forget to manually flush the old unnecessary logs:
`journalctl --vacuum-time=1d`

Comment: Won't there be any problem if you mask these two services? Also, how exactly do you mask them?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, as @FliegendeWurst have written above: `systemctl mask systemd-journal-flush keyboard-setup` is the command to mask these services and I didn't see any problems with that. Remember about flushing logs. Cheers