# Ubuntu 18.04 Boots Even Slower After Disabling Networking & Putting 'noresume' to the Boot kernel?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, kernel

I notice how my Ubuntu 18 boots very slow, so much slower than Windows that previously installed on the same machine. I don't use dual-boot, my machine is :

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8 
64-bit, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
```

NVIDIA was quite problematic and causing boot issues, so I had to put some kernel boot parameters. Now it looks like this :

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi pci=noaer
 acpi_enforce_resources=lax intel_pstate=disable acpi_osi=!Windows
 2012"
```

The default booting time is : **47s**.

[image]

I followed suggestion from this post : [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04), while some answers helped other people, it doesn't work on me.

**What I have tried :**

1. Added `noresume` parameter in kernel boot. Literally from the post above, someone cut booting time by 31s !

   > *I upgraded to 18.04 yesterday and I had the same problem (it took 52*
   >   *seconds to boot). After setting the "noresume" parameter, it took 21*
   >   *seconds.*

   Result : (sorry forgot to take a screenshot): **57s** (10s slower). Why ?
2. Decrease time process for Network and configuring the timeout for Start Job and Stop Jobs by changing :

   ```
   /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service
   ```

   Change `TimeoutStartSec=5min` to `TimeoutStartSec=5s`.

   Also,

   ```
   /etc/systemd/system.conf
   ```

   change :

   ```
   DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s
   DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
   ```

   Result : **Failed to boot**. (Stuck at booting screen)
3. Disable Networking during booting :

   ```
   systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
   ```

   Result : Booting time was **51s** (4s slower).

[image]

Why did I miss from steps above ? How did my machine ended up booting slower ?
Why did `noresume` which was supposed to prevent resume partition makes it slower instead ? Any other advice to decrease booting time ?

**UPDATE**

Following suggestion from [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix), I tried :

4. Disable networking as in step (3), and remove the journal flush service and vacuum it by changing :

   ```
   nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf
   ```

   change

   ```
   Storage=auto
   SystemMaxUse=50M
   SystemMaxFileSize=1G
   SystemMaxFiles=5
   ```

   My original journal disk usage was 2G, now it's down to 200MB. But `system-journal-flush.service` time doesn't seem to get faster, it's still 11s.
   Also, before changing its settings, flushing time was 3.xx s. Now it's 10.xx s instead.

[image]

Result, booting time : **52s** (5s slower).

[image]

5. Disabling tor-service :

   ```
   /etc/default/tor
   ```

   change to `RUN_DAEMON="no"`  and run

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable tor.service
   ```

   Then added `video=SVIDEO-1:d` parameter to the boot kernel (following solution from : [Long Kernel Boot Segment in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111033/long-kernel-boot-segment-in-18-04?rq=1)).
   And masked `systemd-journal-flush.service` and the `keyboard-setup.service` (following solution from : [Long boot time Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093804/long-boot-time-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1)).

Result. Booting time : **45s**. (**2s faster**), but I believe it can be improved.
On the second trial : **47s** (no improvement).
I really thought disabling tor-service would give me 5~7s faster booting time since it originally took 10-13s in booting time.

[image]

Still confused at how `noresume` parameter, disabling networking and vacuum logs from journal lead to slower booting time instead. Further suggestions will be appreciated !

**UPDATE 2**

6. Install `haveged`. Booting time : **49s** (2s slower)

[image]

Just why.

Comment: Can go though line by line and google which services are safe to disable at start up.  Can also remove snapd, but some apps are only available as snaps now.  Will also need to replace some removed snaps with deb versions.  I don't have enough knowledge to tell you which are safe to remove or disable.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, I'm aware snap can slow down my machine as well, but I need snap on my system. I'm currently checking each service, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably disable network waiting altogether:

- [What does NetworkManager-wait-online.service do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do/1018731#1018731)

Remove the journal flush service and vacuum it instead:

- [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service/1094543#1094543)
- [Systemd logs (`journalctl`) are too large and slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow/1012913#1012913)

Slow `snapd` times can be sped up by jiggling your mouse at boot time:

- [Long boot delay on Ubuntu loading/splash screen following regular dist-upgrade on clean SSD install (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the journal logs stuff, thanks I learned something new ! I've updated my question, I tried combination of your suggestions : disabling networking + vacuum journal logs + moving mouse & touchpad. Result booting time : 52 seconds (still 5 seconds slower). I see in `blame` that tor-service is taking up 13 seconds, I'm gonna try to disable that. But I'm still confused at how `noresume`, disabling network and vacuuming logs make it slower instead.